# Can I add a user with limited privileges to my organization in AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online

Is it possible to add a user to an ArcGIS Online organization without giving them access to everything that's shared within that organization?

I'm thinking about contractors from other (small) organizations that do not have their own ArcGIS account, and only need temporary access to a limited set of data.

**UPDATE**: That user should have *read or write* access to certain selected elements only, let's say one WebMap. Everything else should be hidden, including items that are shared company wide.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit privileges by user by assigning them to a role.  Roles can be designed and configured by AGOL Admin.  Once roles are set, you can limit which AGOL objects are accessible to a user by limiting them to a particular group.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a group, add only those contractors, then share the limited access data to that group

Comment: But they would also be part of the organization and thus see everything that's shared company wide.

Answer (score 0):

We achieved this by purchasing Viewer accounts from ESRI, ~ £100 per person per year.

So lets say you buy 2 accounts, these are accounts in your organisation but are User type viewer. When you add them to your organisation you get AGOL to send them an email so they have login details. As @Maksim indicates you could then add them to a group and fine tune what they see, so for example only maps/data tagged to a specific group.

A Viewer User Type has no ability to edit, create or publish data within your organisation and by assigning them to specific groups you hide all your other content from them.

As they have to log into AGOL it means you are not sharing your data publicly.

You would need to contact your local ESRI team to purchase the Viewer accounts. I found it painless and easy to set up.

Comment: But doesn't a viewer account have (read) access to everything shared within the organization? I've updated my question and tried to make myself clearer.

Comment: If you want them to have write capability I think you would need to purchase a creator user type (which is more expensive) and then limit them by assigning them to specific groups.